# Why iOS FaceBook Share Shows Empty Image box even the image is provided?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, uidocumentinteraction

All Works Fine except when I press **Facebook** share button in my iOS app, it loads and shows me an **Empty image** box. Any idea? 
Log error:  **[*Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior*]**

```
- (void)share {
    _img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"face11.jpg"];
    NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/tmptmpimg.png"];
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_img, 1.0) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    NSString *path1 = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/tmptmpimg.ig"];
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_img, 1.0) writeToFile:path1 atomically:YES];

    NSLog(@"Path %@",path);
    _documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
     _documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1]];
    _documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
    [_documentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
}

- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller willBeginSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application 
    {
    NSString *savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/tmptmpimg.ig"];
       [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_img, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];
        controller.URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath];

    NSLog(@"SavePath %@",savePath);
    controller.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    }
```

Comment: I have faced same issue. It rises with simulatetors, works fine in devices.

Comment: how come it doesn't work in my device . Do you know what to do ?

Comment: use FBSDKPhotoShare..

Comment: use slcomposer...& instagrame code..

Comment: i want this to be fixed